# IEqualityComparer<T> not working for 'Contains' method

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

Okay, so I have the following classes/interfaces

`FilterFileViewModel`, `CategoryViewModel`, `IFilterViewModel`, `ICategoryViewModel`.

Inheritance is set up as follows:

```
IFilterViewMode : IEqualityComparer<IFilterViewModel>
ICategoryViewModel : IFilterViewModel
FilterViewModel : ViewModel, IFilterViewModel
CategoryViewModel :FilterViewModel, ICategoryViewModel
```

And I have implemented `IEqualityComparer` in the abstract class `FilterViewModel`.

Now, I have an `IEnumerable<ICategoryViewModel>`, but if I call "Contains" on it, it doesn't seem to use the `Equals` method I have implemented at `FilterViewModel`.

I can see that it's most likely because `ICategoryViewModel` doesn't have the `Equals` method... so the only solution I can think of is to have a collection of `IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>` instead, but this isn't ideal.

Can anyone think of a better way to structure this?

Comment: have you implemented the GetHashCode() method as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the purpose of `IEqualityComparer<IFilterViewModel>` interface. It is not common to implement it in your model objects. Rather, you implement it in a special helper class, and use it to tweak the interpretation of equality in situations when you need that. This is usually done in situations when you have no control over the `Equals` method of the class.

If you want classes themselves to know how to compare for equality, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on the classes themselves. If you want to force subclasses to supply type-specific `Equals`, use `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
IFilterViewMode : IEquatable<IFilterViewModel>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to implement `GetHashCode` even if your current code path does not require it.

Comment: You're right - and I have had that at one point, but it wasn't working either.

The "Contains" method I am calling on an IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> just doesn't seem to call to the "Equals" method on FilterViewModel.

Comment: Edit: It has to be implemented at the exact level that it is used. So IEquatable<ICustomerViewModel> will not work for a CustomerViewModel.